# How to scrape data from a website and write to a csv in a specified format in R?

Tags: python, r, excel, web-scraping, booking.com-api

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.booking.com/country.html.

The idea is to extract all numbers regarding any kind of accommodation listed for a particular country.

The output needs to have the list of all countries in ‘column A’ of an Excel file and the relevant number of listings for different property types (Ex. Apartments, Hostels, Resorts, etc.) in each respective country adjacent to the country names in separate columns.

I need to capture all the details for all the property types for a given country.

[image: The below image describes the output format required.]

The above image describes the output format required in Excel. I am able to get the country using the below code but not the property types and their respective data.

How to get the data iteratively in function for all the countries and write in a csv.

```
library(rvest)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://www.booking.com/country.html"

bookingdata <- read_html(url)

#extracting the country
country <- html_nodes(bookingdata, "h2 > a") %>% 
  html_text()
write.csv(country, 'D:\\web scraping\\country.csv' ,row.names = FALSE)
print(country)

#extracting the data inside the inner div 
html_nodes(bookingdata, "div >div > div > ul > li > a")%>%
  html_text()
for (i in country) {
print(i)
html_nodes(pg, "ul > li > a") %>% 
  html_text()
  print(accomodation)
}

#getting all the data
accomodation <- html_nodes(pg, "ul > li > a") %>% 
  html_text()

#separating the numbers
accomodation.num <- (str_extract(accomodation, "[0-9]+"))
#separating the characters
accomodation.char <- (str_extract(accomodation,"[aA-zZ]+"))
#separating unique characters
unique(accomodation.char)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.booking.com/country.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'block_third block_third--flag-module'}):
    country = [(country.text).replace('\n', '')
               for country in item.findAll('a')]
    data.append(country)

final = []
for item in data:
    final.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(final)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

View Output Online: [Click Here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=718f50ee944de5bc511451edafdbf944ce2e368e1f840d25b6b1592b7d85173819f68de7a3cf14eaa12c0acc8886dc3c9d18e65f15ec8c3cb01e4088f8bba831)

[image]

Another Version for user requirements via CHAT:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.booking.com/country.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for item in soup.select('div.block_third.block_third--flag-module'):
    country = [(country.text).replace('\n', '')
               for country in item.select('a')]
    data.append(country)

final = []
for item in data:
    final.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(final).set_index(0)
df.index.name = 'location'
split = df.stack().str.extract('^(?P<freq>[\d,]+)\s+(?P<category>.*)').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
pvt = split.pivot(columns='category', values='freq')
pvt.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
pvt.reset_index().to_csv('output2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: When I try to run this code in my local machine it throws this error [ https://jsfiddle.net/gxjh5tky/ ] please help me in resolving this

Comment: @Raghavi use `r = requests.get('https://www.booking.com/country.html', verify=False)`

Comment: Thank you so much. How to bring this output in the required format(refer above image). Can we use excel or python for that?

Comment: @Raghavi you welcome, but in case if I arranged the data, so it's will not be nice. because the data is not usually matching together ! have you checked `output.csv` in your current directory ?

Comment: Yes Its my current directory. And the data is not matching, in that case the cells must be left with "blanks" for the country which dont have the properties.

Comment: like that ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b3ovNdzn_-5ZbgUqr3MFq5V6VXxE4Etm/view